# Matplotlib for Python 3 and Linux

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I understand that Matplotlib has been ported to Python 3 ([matplotlib-python-3-thanks-cape-town-group](http://pythonsprints.com/2011/04/8/matplotlib-python-3-thanks-cape-town-group/)).

However, it seems that I can only find Windows executables.

The [matplotlib-py3](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-py3) page claims that it was merged into Matplotlib.

Does anybody knows where I can find Matplotlib 1.2 development branch most likely to work on Linux. Does anybody successfully use it with Python 3?

Comment: Sure! (In fact, it's much more heavily tested on Linux with python3 than on Windows.) However, binaries aren't typically distributed for Linux directly, so you won't find a "download" link on the webpage. Either search for it in your distro's repositories or if it's not in the repos for your distro, build it from source (which is quite simple in most cases). As far as which branch to use, just build from the main matplotlib github tip. (Or the current release, if I remember right.)

Comment: Thanks... Just for the record, I downloaded the stable (currently v1.1.0) ".tar.gz". The INSTALL file provided build and install command. Seems working fine with Python 3.2 and Ubuntu 11.10!!

Comment: matplotlib 1.1.0 probably won't work with Python 3 - it's in the [development version](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib), which will become 1.2

Comment: @ThomasK - I'm pretty sure py3k support was merged in before 1.1.0 was released.  I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 5):

As @ThomasK mentioned, the [git master branch](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) is the place to get the current Python3 compatible version of matplotlib, and it will be where v1.2 is cut from. If there are any problems that come up, please file them as bugs.

Just a heads up that there will soon be a bug-fix only v1.1.1 release, which will still not be Py3k compatible, so when you hear about it, please ignore it as far as Python3 is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a pretty old question, but I'm currently able to use matplotlib (1.2) with python3 using pip:

```
pip-python3 install matplotlib
```

worked for me, using python 3.3.

Comment: I think `apt-get install python3-matplotlib` will work now too, but my ubuntu is too old to test it